# Why did Ramsay Bolton transform Theon Greyjoy to Reek?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

As we saw in *Game of Thrones* that Ramsay Bolton tortured, mentally and physically almost constantly, Theon Greyjoy. Then why, instead of killing him, did he transform him to Reek who is completely psychologically broken?

Comment: IMHO it makes very little sense in the TV version, [the book version](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Reek) shows this is the result of a number of events.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When Ramsay captures Theon , he converts him into Reek for following reasons:-

1. By keeping Theon alive, he has a hostage from the Greyjoy family, who are always a threat for the 'Warden of North'.
2. He finds a loyal friend and servant by brainwashing him. Now, Theon had some personal motivation but Reek has none. He is completely faithful to Ramsay.
3. He can use him time to time as Theon.

   a. He did for negotiating with the Ironborn garrison holding it in an attempt to convince them to surrender the fortress to the Boltons.

   b. To give Sansa and Ramsay marriage value in the eyes of the North. As Theon was ward of Stark, his presence approves that Sansa is not forced into marriage. She is married in presence of her family. As Theon is like family for her.

Comment: You seems to forget that this was never happened in TV show.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Thanks for reminding me. I believe its fine now.

Comment: In the books the girl getting married isn't Sansa.

Comment: "To give Sansa and Ramsay marriage value in the eyes of the North." The North doesn't give a f*** about some Ironborn king's offspring, especially not considering he's responsible for killing Bran & Rickon and for Winterfell being burnt down.

Comment: Ya I know however in show girl is sans a . I removed some information as this question is from show